# Generics in conjunction with primitive objects

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, primitive-types

I'm in the process of writing a small personal library of sorting methods and data structures and I'm attempting to make my classes more robust by allowing them to work with generic types, using `<T extends Comparable<T>>`. This works perfectly when I'm reading in a text file full of type `String`, or need to store custom class objects that have a `compareTo()` method. What I'm unsure about is how to extend this functionality to a text file full of numbers, of all type `int` for example. In my understanding, `int` is a primitive type, and does not have any methods, including `compareTo()`. This prevents my classes from being able to accept type `int`.

- My first idea is to wrap each `int` in an `object<T>`, and just feed it in.
- Is this a clean solution, or is there more of a *best practices* approach?

Thanks.

Answer, courtesy of @dasblinkenlight:

- "Java team has optimized these wrapper classes, and even built special tricks into the compiler / JVM, to ensure that their performance is as good as possible for a wrapper class", so creating a custom wrapper class has no benefits, and should not be the approach.

Edit: modified title for more accurate reference.

Comment: Just use the wrapper classes for primitives, such as ``Integer`` for ``int``.

Comment: Can you just use `Integer` instead of `int` ? `int i=0; Integer iObject=i`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My first idea is to wrap each int in an `object<T>`, and just feed it in.

You don't have to - that is what [`java.lang.Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is for. Similar wrapper types exist for all other primitive types of Java.

> Is this a clean solution, or is there more of a best practices approach?

It depends on your performance requirements. If wrapping primitives is acceptable (it is for the majority of applications) then you have a working approach.

In the unlikely scenario that this approach is not fast enough you would need to build special classes for each primitive type, in a way similar to Java's take on streams for primitives ([`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), [`LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html), [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html), etc.)

Comment: This is the sort of answer that I was looking for. I haven't ever thought of classes like java.lang.Integer as wrappers for this sort of functionality. Would I be correct in assuming that there would be absolutely no performance difference, and no point in making a custom wrapper class?

Comment: @ChrisPhillips Right, Java team has optimized these wrapper classes, and even built special tricks into the compiler / JVM, to ensure that their performance is as good as possible for a wrapper class.